# How to complain when the offender cannot be located?

Tags: property, ownership, noise

I am pursuing a noise complaint in the London Borough of Bromley. The noise is coming from a car park beneath a block of flats. I know the company that manages the car park, but they are not responsible for its infrastructure or maintenance, and I am unable to locate the building owner or building manager.

I tried using the land registry, but this only allows me to search for the owners of individual flats, and not the building itself or its car park.

The council has deemed that the noise is not a nuisance (which I disagree with), so I am considering private action, but before I can approach the Ombudsman or the courts I need to show evidence that I have contacted the building owners. So how can I proceed if I am not able to locate them?

Comment: I'm not sure your question is on topic here, but are you make a recurring payment to anyone? If so I would start with them.

Comment: 1. Your question risks being closed because it seems to ask for specific legal advice, although the question headline is general. 2. If you can find other people who have been disturbed it becomes a public nuisance.

Comment: @IKnowNothing Yes, we pay rent to our landlord but they have no connection to the neighbouring building and are not able to help us.

Comment: @Lag My neighbour is also affected. How could I rephrase the question to make it more general? I am asking, in a general sense, how one might raise a complaint against a building owner that cannot be identified.

Comment: @Dan Try phrasing it as if it were a hypothetical scenario. You can describe the same circumstances from from a third person's point of view instead of your own. "Suppose Alice has a noise complaint..."

Answer (score 3):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

In this context - nuisance - proceedings can be brought against the the premises owner *or occupier* if the person responsible for the nuisance can't be found. See [section 82(4)(c) Environmental Protection Act 1990](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/43/section/82):

> 4. Proceedings for an order under subsection (2) above shall be brought—
>
> (a) except in a case falling within [F5paragraph (b), (c) or (d) below], against the person responsible for the nuisance;
>
> (b) where the nuisance arises from any defect of a structural character, against the owner of the premises;
>
> (c) where the person responsible for the nuisance cannot be found, against the owner or occupier of the premises.

[Guidance on Shelter: Statutory nuisance action by individuals](https://england.shelter.org.uk/professional_resources/legal/housing_conditions/local_authority_duties_to_deal_with_poor_conditions/local_authority_statutory_nuisance_duties#title-10):

> The aggrieved person must serve a notice of intention to bring proceedings on the person responsible for the statutory nuisance[62] except where:
>
> ... the person responsible cannot be found. In this case, the notice should be served on the owner or occupier of the premises. [cites s.82(4)(c) Environmental Protection Act 1990, as above]

Comment: If the noise is coming from a car park beneath a block of flats, then who is the occupier? It is not really fair to single out any one flat.

Comment: "The company that manages the car park".